# How do I call the superclass comparator (spaceship) method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, spaceship-operator

I'm trying to a comparator for a class without rewriting the comparison logic from the superclass, but for some reason I cannot get the return value from the superclass comparator. This issue can be demonstrated with the following snippet:

```
class A
  def <=>(other)
    puts "Calling A's comparator"
    return 1
  end
end

class B < A
  attr_accessor :foo

  def initialize(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end

  def <=>(other)
    if self.foo == other.foo
      c = super.<=>(other)
      puts "The return value from calling the superclass comparator is of type #{c.class}"
    else
      self.foo <=> other.foo
    end
  end
end

b1 = B.new(1)
b2 = B.new(1)
b1 <=> b2
```

And I get the following output:

```
Calling A's comparator
The return value from calling the A's comparator is of type NilClass
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`super` in Ruby doesn't work like that. `super` calls the superclasses implementation of *this method*. So:

```
c = super(other)
```

You also don't have to provide the explicit argument, as `super` with no arguments just calls the superclass method with the same arguments as the subclass implementation revived:

```
c = super
```

Only use explicit `super` arguments if you need to change the arguments given to the superclass implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`super` is a base method, you don't need to call `<=>` on it:

```
def <=>(other)
  if self.foo == other.foo
    c = super
    puts "The return value from calling the superclass comparator is of type #{c.class}"
  else
    self.foo <=> other.foo
  end
end
```

Comment: Arguments are provided automatically when you call `super`, there is no need to specify other.